# Spring Boot: Why isn't entity being scanned in createQuery when using multiple datasources?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.0. I have 2 data sources one for oracle and one for h2 defined in application.properties.
I have to 2 `@Configuration` classes for the data configurations. Both classes implement:

- `DataSource`
- `PlatformTransactionManager`
- `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

In `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` I set up:

- `setDataSource`
- `setPackagesToScan`
- `setJpaVendorAdapter`

The application starts up properly, I can even do `.findAll` on the table in the H2 database, however
as soon as I start executing custom methods in the repository implementation, such as this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
private Optional<List<Foo>> findFooByState(Optional<Integer> id, Foo.State state) {
CriteriaBuilder cp = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> cqFoo= cp.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> fooRoot = cqFoo.from(Foo.class);
[...]
```

Spring throws an exception such as:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an entity: class foo.Foo;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class foo.Foo] with root cause
```

Package `foo` is added in `setPackagesToScan` as I wrote earlier.
I have tried various things with `@Transactional`, e.g. remove it, add the name of the transaction manager specified in the `DataSource` in it, move the `@Transactional` to the `@GetMapping`, but none of it helped.

Does anybody have any clue what am I doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Most probably you haven`t configured JPA repositories base packages to pick up different entities for different data sources. You can have a look at my [guide on how to configure two data sources](https://medium.com/ifelsecoder/spring-boot-spring-jpa-multiple-data-sources-3ac97de11b04)
in Spring Boot application. Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but yeah the packages were added, the real problem was the repository’s persistencecontext config. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was lame. I had to:

1. `setPersistenceUnitName` in the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instantiation method
2. I had to use the proper `@PersistenceContext` with the proper `unitName`

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could elaborate and provide a sample, or link to an article or a video. Thanks in advance.